# Sublime Text 2 Service

Tags: shell, service, sublimetext2, automator

I'm attempting to make an open in Sublime Text 2 service via Automator.

I am doing this by:

- Running Automator
- Adding a new service
- Adding "Run Shell Script"
- Setting Shell to `/bin/zsh`
- Entering a command line of: `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n $@`
- Setting "Service receives selected" to "files or folders"
- Click save

Screenshot:

[image]

However, whenever I try to open a folder via right-click > services > "Open in Sublime", a new ST2 window is opened but with a randomly named text file (ie subl stdin N188RN.txt) and it's output is the path of the folder opened (ie: /Users/me/Desktop/project).

Screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way I can modify the automator command line to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting `Pass input:` value to `as arguments`:

[image]

Comment: Beautifully simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Enable OSX Mountain Lion Context Menu Launch:**

1. Open Automator. Add new service.
2. Search for "Run Shell Script". Drag over to the panel on the right (or double click it).
3. Enter:

   `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -a $@`
4. Set "Pass Input:" to "As Arguments"
5. Set "Shell" to "bin/zsh"
6. Set "Services Receives Selected:" to "files or folders"
7. Save as "Open-in-Sublime".

To use: right-click on a file or folder, and click 'Open-in-Sublime' in the 'Services' menu at the bottom of the context menu.

**Enable OSX Mountain Lion Terminal Launch:**

1. At the command line enter:

   `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin`
2. Then enter:

   `sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime`
3. `ln` creates a link. `-s` makes it a symbolic link.
4. You may need to prefix the command with `sudo` if it doesn't work.
5. Restart the terminal.

To use:

user$ `sublime .` [This will open the current folder structure in Sublime]

user$ `sublime <filename>` [This will open the desired file in Sublime]

Comment: Lots of other tutorials recommend pushing the symbolic link to `/bin/subl` but your suggestion of `/usr/local/bin/subl` was just what I needed to get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Pass input: value to as arguments.

And `"/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"` Path should in double quotes.